# Output based on a specific key (group_by)

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON output. I would like the output to be grouped by the common TZ.

Input:

```
{
  "TZ": "5f105439-a0a7-4134-9e98-87553d434b35",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8056-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2331"
}
{
  "TZ": "5f105439-a0a7-4134-9e98-87553d434b35",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8051-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2332"
}
{
  "TZ": "5f105439-a0a7-4134-9e98-87553d434b35",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8054-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2437"
}
{
  "TZ": "5f105439-a0a7-4134-9e98-87553d434b35",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8052-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2438"
}
{
  "TZ": "5f105439-a0a7-4134-9e98-87553d434b35",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8050-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2439"
}
{
  "TZ": "5f105439-a0a7-4134-9e98-87553d434b35",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8053-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2440"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8056-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2331"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8051-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2332"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8054-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2437"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8052-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2438"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8050-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2439"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8053-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2440"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1814"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8059-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1815"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8058-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1816"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8057-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1817"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1818"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "577d18d8-519e-11e9-a1e8-005056962661",
  "TNN": "edg1"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "60971284-519e-11e9-9f28-00505696744e",
  "TNN": "edg2"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "67f2aaa2-519e-11e9-a7ff-00505696f042",
  "TNN": "edg3"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "711dc120-519e-11e9-ba09-005056965018",
  "TNN": "edg4"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "7acbdc7a-519e-11e9-99c3-005056965c74",
  "TNN": "edg5"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "82830f7e-519e-11e9-b1a5-00505696749d",
  "TNN": "edg6"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "8ac12ffe-519e-11e9-8bf9-00505696d434",
  "TNN": "edg7"
}
{
  "TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
  "TN": "943a9d40-519e-11e9-a918-00505696771c",
  "TNN": "edg8"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1814"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8059-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1815"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8058-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1816"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8057-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1817"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1818"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "577d18d8-519e-11e9-a1e8-005056962661",
  "TNN": "edg1"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "60971284-519e-11e9-9f28-00505696744e",
  "TNN": "edg2"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "67f2aaa2-519e-11e9-a7ff-00505696f042",
  "TNN": "edg3"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "711dc120-519e-11e9-ba09-005056965018",
  "TNN": "edg4"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "7acbdc7a-519e-11e9-99c3-005056965c74",
  "TNN": "edg5"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "82830f7e-519e-11e9-b1a5-00505696749d",
  "TNN": "edg6"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "8ac12ffe-519e-11e9-8bf9-00505696d434",
  "TNN": "edg7"
}
{
  "TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
  "TN": "943a9d40-519e-11e9-a918-00505696771c",
  "TNN": "edg8"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[
"TZ": "5f105439-a0a7-4134-9e98-87553d434b35"
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8056-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2331"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8051-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2332"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8054-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2437"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8052-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2438"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8050-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2439"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8053-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2440"
}
]

[
"TZ": "8dc3bff5-09b2-4518-81e8-39a8136f885f",
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8056-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2331"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8051-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2332"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8054-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2437"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5110-8052-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2438"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0030-5210-8050-b3c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2439"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-0046-3310-8053-b2c04f433432",
  "TNN": "a2440"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1814"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8059-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1815"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8058-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1816"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8057-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1817"
}
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1818"
}
{
  "TN": "577d18d8-519e-11e9-a1e8-005056962661",
  "TNN": "edg1"
}
{
  "TN": "60971284-519e-11e9-9f28-00505696744e",
  "TNN": "edg2"
}
{
  "TN": "67f2aaa2-519e-11e9-a7ff-00505696f042",
  "TNN": "edg3"
}
{
  "TN": "711dc120-519e-11e9-ba09-005056965018",
  "TNN": "edg4"
}
{
  "TN": "7acbdc7a-519e-11e9-99c3-005056965c74",
  "TNN": "edg5"
}
{
  "TN": "82830f7e-519e-11e9-b1a5-00505696749d",
  "TNN": "edg6"
}
{
  "TN": "8ac12ffe-519e-11e9-8bf9-00505696d434",
  "TNN": "edg7"
}
{
  "TN": "943a9d40-519e-11e9-a918-00505696771c",
  "TNN": "edg8"
}
]

"TZ": "e1c4ad26-2b2b-41cf-b7be-155704018580",
{
  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1814"
}
{

  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8059-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1815"
}
{

  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8058-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1816"
}
{

  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3810-8057-b9c04f4c4e32",
  "TNN": "d1817"
}
{

  "TN": "4c4c4544-004a-3710-8050-b9c04f394e32",
  "TNN": "d1818"
}
{

  "TN": "577d18d8-519e-11e9-a1e8-005056962661",
  "TNN": "edg1"
}
{

  "TN": "60971284-519e-11e9-9f28-00505696744e",
  "TNN": "edg2"
}
{

  "TN": "67f2aaa2-519e-11e9-a7ff-00505696f042",
  "TNN": "edg3"
}
{

  "TN": "711dc120-519e-11e9-ba09-005056965018",
  "TNN": "edg4"
}
{

  "TN": "7acbdc7a-519e-11e9-99c3-005056965c74",
  "TNN": "edg5"
}
{

  "TN": "82830f7e-519e-11e9-b1a5-00505696749d",
  "TNN": "edg6"
}
{

  "TN": "8ac12ffe-519e-11e9-8bf9-00505696d434",
  "TNN": "edg7"
}
{

  "TN": "943a9d40-519e-11e9-a918-00505696771c",
  "TNN": "edg8"
}
```

I could not find a way to make this work with group_by and map functions. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: your output is not a valid JSON, please fix it

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the following or a variation thereof :

```
jq --slurp 'group_by(.TZ) | map({TZ:.[0].TZ, values:map({TN, TNN})})'
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/JKxcjOk9Wc)

Comment: excellent this worked. I was trying to use the double map without values.

Comment: @amrutha Glad to hear it. Consider accepting the answer since it solved your problem.